# Material UI autocomplete with datepicker inside it not popping

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I am trying to fit a datetime picker inside the paper of MUI autocomplete.
Tried [mui datepicker](https://material-ui.com/components/pickers/#material-ui-pickers) and tried to force open the datepicker but no luck.
The native seems to work to an extend but it still needs to wire the date selection click to close the poper.
here is demo:

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-pmgzp

Plz advise

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to integrate `DatePicker` with `autocomplete`. I did it with [useAutoComplete](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#useautocomplete)

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useAutocomplete } from "@mui/base/AutocompleteUnstyled";
import { DateRangePicker } from "mui-daterange-picker";
import { TextField } from "@mui/material";
import InputAdornment from "@mui/material/InputAdornment";
import CalendarMonthOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/CalendarMonthOutlined";
import moment, { Moment } from "moment";

export interface IDatePickerProps {
  name: string;
  startDateLabel: string;
  endDateLabel: string;
  value: [Moment, Moment];
  setFieldValue: (
    field: string,
    value: [Moment, Moment],
    shouldValidate?: boolean
  ) => void;
}

export default function UseAutocomplete({
  name = "datepicker",
  value = [moment(), moment().add(1, "months")],
  startDateLabel = "2022-10-1",
  endDateLabel = "2022-12-1",
  setFieldValue
}) {
  const { getRootProps, getInputLabelProps, getInputProps } = useAutocomplete({
    id: "use-autocomplete-demo",
    options: []
  });

  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const toggle = () => setOpen(!open);

  return (
    <div>
      <>
        <div {...getRootProps()}>
          <label {...getInputLabelProps()}>{name}</label>
          <TextField
            {...getInputProps()}
            name={name}
            placeholder={`${startDateLabel} - ${endDateLabel}`}
            onClick={toggle}
            InputProps={{
              endAdornment: (
                <InputAdornment position="end">
                  <CalendarMonthOutlinedIcon />
                </InputAdornment>
              )
            }}
            value={`${moment(value[0]).format("YYYY-MM-DD")} - ${moment(
              value[1]
            ).format("YYYY-MM-DD")}`}
          />
        </div>
        {
          <DateRangePicker
            open={open}
            toggle={toggle}
            onChange={(range) => {
              let selectedValues = [
                moment(range.startDate),
                moment(range.endDate)
              ];
              setFieldValue(selectedValues);
            }}
          />
        }
      </>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Output:
[image: Datepicker using autoComplete]